# MSK bootstrap server endpoint fixed between cluster recreations

Tags: aws-msk, aws-nlb

What would be the recommended way to achieve static ip addres or DNS A record or alias for brokers that does not change on MSK cluster recreation? Considering how rare this is supposed to happen, putting an NLB in front of it seems like an overkill and it maybe even causes some issues?